# Remove bad but plausible values from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

I have a basic numpy array of values (called timeseries, and given below). The values just above 0 generally represent bad values (ideally, they would have been Nan'd but alas...), and so I want to remove them from the array. My issue is that for other instances of timeseries, these values around 0 could be plausible. FYI, the values are sea surface temperature measurements and if the measurements were taken near or in polar regions a value close to 0 is plausible.

My question is: is there a clever way I can remove these data points? I have thought about using np.diff to try and locate 'step-changes' in the data, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. I've also thought about using stats, such as a window around the mean value of timeseries, but because the values are bimodal this isn't going to work; for example, in the case below the mean value would be around 9  - which is not representative of the true mean (i.e.,with bad data removed)) - and so a window around this value would remove all good values.

```
array([[ 17.7804203 ],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [ 17.7335453 ],
   [ 17.72670937],
   [ 17.72670937],
   [ 17.75502968],
   [ 17.81459999],
   [ 17.89565468],
   [ 17.98159218],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [ 17.9210453 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Without a-priori model-information there is not much you can do. And this model-info is not stated that formally. So this example has more or less 2 peaks (my wording is bad/informal; imagine a number-line and there are many points at some x-axis value; and some at some other x-axis value). Is that always the case? The one around zero is constant. Is that always the case? If yes; maybe use some 1d-clustering to obtain those 2 (mean-)values; then check the variance of both (using class-information from clustering) and throw away all values of the class with the lower variance.

Comment: you basically need a 1D [clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) algorithm to classify your bimodal (multimodal) data. I'm a particular fan of [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) for not needing to know how many groups exist beforehand, and being capable of identifying within a cluster both primary members and outliers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. One idea I've had is to find repeat values less than 0.1 (as the bad value seems to be the same within a given array). Then just delete these values on a case by case basis. But this is still not a perfect solution

Comment: Are the plausible near-zero values in the same array as the erroneous near-zero values, or are they in some other array we don't have to worry about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some hacky demo, trying to learn something from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094454/how-would-one-use-kernel-density-estimation-as-a-1d-clustering-method-in-scikit) (SO's clustering expert).

I changed some things and won't give any guarantees:

- labeling-method

  - important: i'm deviating from his underlying theory here (his approach should be superior)!
  - i'm just labeling according to the nearest-center (like in kmeans)
- argrelextrema's comparator (needed for your data which has not unique values!)
- using heuristic bandwith-selection (by not setting a constant!)

This code uses [kernel-density-estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) **to obtain a 1d-clustering which chooses k automatically**. Now it sounds, you wan't to always use `k=2`, but this here is more general.

So using it for your data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

x = np.array([[ 17.7804203 ],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [ 17.7335453 ],
   [ 17.72670937],
   [ 17.72670937],
   [ 17.75502968],
   [ 17.81459999],
   [ 17.89565468],
   [ 17.98159218],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [  0.08901367],
   [ 17.9210453 ],])
   # [5.4],
   # [5.41],
   # [5.3],
   # [5.35]])

np.random.shuffle(x)                                             # just for demo

kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian').fit(x)               # bandwith heuristic
s = np.linspace(np.amin(x), np.amax(x))
e = kde.score_samples(s.reshape(-1,1))

ma = argrelextrema(e, np.greater_equal )[0]
s_ma = np.array([s[ma[i]] for i in range(len(ma))])           # cluster centers
n_clusters = len(s_ma)                                        # n_clusters

# class labeling
Y = cdist(x, s_ma[np.newaxis].T)
labels = np.empty(len(x), dtype=int)
for x_ind in range(len(x)):
    labels[x_ind] = np.argmin(Y[x_ind, :])

# plot classification
xs = np.arange(len(x))
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, n_clusters))
for label in range(n_clusters):
    inds = np.where(labels == label)[0]
    plt.scatter(xs[inds], x[inds], color=colors[label], s=40)
plt.show()
```

output this classification (remember: i permuted the x-values):

[image]

Now let's add 4 new points around 5 (as i'm lazy and added them to the end, i used the mentioned permutation). Just uncomment those lines in the code.

Output:

[image]

So in the first case, we obtained two clusters, now we got three (i swear: `n_clusters=3` although my matplotlib code changes the colors somehow...)!

Feel free to play around with this. You might use my approach in the comment, using the labels to extract classes, calculate the variance and throw away the class with the lowest one. But that's depending on your task of course.

For example this code added at the end:

```
# Calculate variance for each class
variances = np.array([np.var(x[np.where(labels == i)[0]]) for i in 
range(n_clusters)])
print(np.hstack([variances[np.newaxis].T, s_ma[np.newaxis].T]))
```

would output:

```
[[  1.92592994e-34   8.90136700e-02]  # variance | cluster_mean
 [  1.92500000e-03   5.20117896e+00]
 [  8.05793565e-03   1.79815922e+01]]
```

which in your case might be interpreted as: throw class 0 away (minimum variance or some thresholding-check: remove all with var < x).

Comment: Thanks @sascha for the suggestion. I will play around with your idea and see where it gets me.