# clustering 1D data and representing clusters on matplotlib histogram

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, histogram, cluster-analysis

I have 1D data in the format of:

```
areas = ...
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.hist(areas, bins=80)
plt.show()
```

The plot of this looks something along the lines of this:

[image]

Now I want to be able to cluster this data. I know that I have the option of either [Kernel Density Estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64272244/4805357) or K-Means. But once I have these values, how am I represent this clusters on the histogram?

Comment: Do you want to plot `KDE` on the `histogram`, is it right ?

Comment: @JayPatel I want the histogram as shown above, but the colors indicating the cluster they these datapoints are from. A legend to show the cluster center for each color would also be very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to figure out your cluster assignment, and then plot each subset of the data individually while taking care that the bins are the same each time.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False

# simulate some fake data
n = 10000
mu1, sigma1 = 0, 1
mu2, sigma2 = 6, 2
a = mu1 + sigma1 * np.random.randn(n)
b = mu2 + sigma2 * np.random.randn(n)
data = np.concatenate([a, b])

# determine which K-Means cluster each point belongs to
cluster_id = KMeans(2).fit_predict(data.reshape(-1, 1))

# determine densities by cluster assignment and plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bins = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 40)
for ii in np.unique(cluster_id):
    subset = data[cluster_id==ii]
    ax.hist(subset, bins=bins, alpha=0.5, label=f"Cluster {ii}")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```