# How do I group data into naturally occurring "Bins"

Tags: c#, arrays, statistics, data-analysis, mathnet-numerics

What approach should I use to sort the following into naturally occurring "bins".

```
   double[] x = { 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24,  
      26, 27, 32, 33, 49, 52, 56,900,1200, 1200, 1500, 2000, 2000,2200,2200 };
```

I've looked at various code for "outliers", "quintiles" and not sure about what approach to take.

If it makes it easier, I'm using C# and might leverage Linq or some other approach to do this.

In my case I want to create two "bins" of drastically different number sets such as:

- NumbersLessThan56
- NumbersGreaterThan900

The thing I want to mathematically compute is that there is a large "multiple of x" gap between Bin1 and Bin2.

I'm experimenting with MathNet to find derivative inflection points, but still figuring this out

Comment: Would this question be a better fit for https://stats.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into "[Jenks natural breaks optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization)" for this type of problem, cf. [1D Number Array Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering).