# Image Quantization with quantums Algorithm question

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across a question and unable to find a feasible solution.

Image Quantization

Given a grayscale mage, each pixels color range from (0 to 255), compress the range of values to a given number of quantum values.

The goal is to do that with the minimum sum of costs needed, the cost of a pixel is defined as the absolute difference between its color and the closest quantum value for it.

Example

There are 3 rows 3 columns, image [[7,2,8], [8,2,3], [9,8 255]] quantums = 3 number of quantum values.The optimal quantum values are (2,8,255) Leading to the minimum sum of costs |7-8| + |2-2| + |8-8| + |8-8| + |2-2| + |3-2| + |9-8| + |8-8| + |255-255| = 1+0+0+0+0+1+1+0+0 = 3

Function description

Complete the solve function provided in the editor. This function takes the following 4 parameters and returns the minimum sum of costs.

n Represents the number of rows in the image

m Represents the number of columns in the image

image Represents the image

quantums Represents the number of quantum values.

Output:
Print a single integer the minimum sum of costs/

```
Constraints: 

1<=n,m<=100
0<=image|i||j|<=255
1<=quantums<=256

Sample Input 1
3
3
7 2 8
8 2 3
9 8 255
10

Sample output 1
0
```

**Explanation**

The optimum quantum values are {0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,255} Leading the minimum sum of costs |7-7| + |2-2| + |8-8| + |8-8| + |2-2| + |3-3| + |9-9| + |8-8| + |255-255| = 0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0 = 0

can anyone help me to reach the solution ?

Comment: When the number of quantums = 1, then this problem reduces to finding the median (or 50th percentile).  Based on this, I'd guess that a first-cut/heruistic for this would be to assign the quantums to cumulative percentiles equal to `100% / (#quantums+1)`.  So for three quantums, assign them to the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentiles.

Comment: ... initially, anyway.  Then I'd find which one of the quantum has the most values "closest" to it, and I'd try incrementing/decrementing it until I got a local minima, then repeat this for the other quantums.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1D Number Array Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering)

Comment: @Welbog the above suggested question does not answer this question in anyway ! Please take back your close request

Comment: It is, in fact, the same problem. You are trying to identify N clusters in one-dimensional data in order to minimize the total distance to the centers of those clusters.

Comment: @Welbog I see answers are using some data science prebuild functions, but this question was asked in a competitive coding exam, I need to write a complete algo in 1hr.
If you can derive an algo from above suggested question, taking my question inputs and output min sum cost, it will be very helpful

Comment: @Welbog No, it *is not* the same problem.  That question is looking for a *k-means* solution.  This question is looking for something that AFAIK, does not have a formal name, but is effectively a *k-median* solution. They are different things with different answers.

Comment: This is solvable using dynamic programming, and is a simple variation on the piecewise least-squares problem (also solvable by DP in 1 dimension.) The only difference is to use a strict penalty on # of pieces (instead of linear penalty) and use the L1 norm instead of L2. There are various resources online explaining the logic: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s14/www/LectureNotes/lecture06.pdf

Comment: Figuring this problem out and implementing it error-free in under 1hr is a difficult task. I would not expect this of anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly if we have as many or more quantums available than distinct pixels, we can return 0 as we set at least enough quantums to each equal one distinct pixel. Now consider setting the quantum at the lowest number of the sorted, grouped list.

```
M = [
  [7, 2, 8],
  [8, 2, 3],
  [9, 8, 255]
]

[(2, 2), (3, 1), (7, 1), (8, 3), (9, 1), (255, 1)]
 2
```

We record the required sum of differences:

```
0 + 0 + 1 + 5 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 7 + 253 = 284
```

Now to update by incrementing the quantum by 1, we observe that we have a movement of 1 per element so all we need is the count of affected elements.

Incremenet 2 to 3

```
3
1 + 1 + 0 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 6 + 252 = 279
```

or

```
284 + 2 * 1 - 7 * 1
= 284 + 2 - 7
= 279
```

Consider traversing from the left with a single quantum, calculating only the effect on pixels in the sorted, grouped list that are on the left side of the quantum value.

To only update the left side when adding a quantum, we have:

```
left[k][q] = min(left[k-1][p] + effect(A, p, q))
```

where `effect` is the effect on the elements in `A` (the sorted, grouped list) as we reduce `p` incrementally and update the effect on the pixels in the range, `[p, q]` according to whether they are closer to `p` or `q`. As we increase `q` for each round of `k`, we can keep the relevant place in the sorted, grouped pixel list with a pointer that moves incrementally.

If we have a solution for

```
left[k][q]
```

where it is the best for pixels on the left side of `q` when including `k` quantums with the rightmost quantum set as the number `q`, then the complete candidate solution would be given by:

```
left[k][q] + effect(A, q, list_end)
  where there is no quantum between q and list_end
```

Time complexity would be `O(n + k * q * q) = O(n + quantums ^ 3)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the input matrix.

Python code:

```
def f(M, quantums):
  pixel_freq = [0] * 256
  
  for row in M:
    for colour in row:
      pixel_freq[colour] += 1
    
  # dp[k][q] stores the best solution up
  # to the qth quantum value, with
  # considering the effect left of
  # k quantums with the rightmost as q 
  dp = [[0] * 256 for _ in range(quantums + 1)]
  
  pixel_count = pixel_freq[0]
  
  for q in range(1, 256):
    dp[1][q] = dp[1][q-1] + pixel_count
    pixel_count += pixel_freq[q]

  predecessor = [[None] * 256 for _ in range(quantums + 1)]
    
  # Main iteration, where the full
  # candidate includes both right and
  # left effects while incrementing the
  # number of quantums.
  for k in range(2, quantums + 1):
    for q in range(k - 1, 256):
      # Adding a quantum to the right
      # of the rightmost doesn't change
      # the left cost already calculated
      # for the rightmost.
      best_left = dp[k-1][q-1]
      predecessor[k][q] = q - 1
      q_effect = 0
      p_effect = 0
      p_count = 0

      for p in range(q - 2, k - 3, -1):
        r_idx = p + (q - p) // 2
        # When the distance between p
        # and q is even, we reassign
        # one pixel frequency to q
        if (q - p - 1) % 2 == 0:
          r_freq = pixel_freq[r_idx + 1]
          q_effect += (q - r_idx - 1) * r_freq
          p_count -= r_freq
          p_effect -= r_freq * (r_idx - p)

        # Either way, we add one pixel frequency
        # to p_count and recalculate
        p_count += pixel_freq[p + 1]
        p_effect += p_count
        effect = dp[k-1][p] + p_effect + q_effect

        if effect < best_left:
          best_left = effect
          predecessor[k][q] = p

      dp[k][q] = best_left

  # Records the cost only on the right
  # of the rightmost quantum
  # for candidate solutions.
  right_side_effect = 0
  pixel_count = pixel_freq[255]
  best = dp[quantums][255]
  best_quantum = 255

  for q in range(254, quantums-1, -1):
    right_side_effect += pixel_count
    pixel_count += pixel_freq[q]
    candidate = dp[quantums][q] + right_side_effect

    if candidate < best:
      best = candidate
      best_quantum = q

  quantum_list = [best_quantum]
  prev_quantum = best_quantum

  for i in range(k, 1, -1):
    prev_quantum = predecessor[i][prev_quantum]
    quantum_list.append(prev_quantum)

  return best, list(reversed(quantum_list))
```

Output:

```py
M = [
  [7, 2, 8],
  [8, 2, 3],
  [9, 8, 255]
]

k = 3

print(f(M, k)) # (3, [2, 8, 255])


M = [
  [7, 2, 8],
  [8, 2, 3],
  [9, 8, 255]
]

k = 10

print(f(M, k)) # (0, [2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255])
```

Comment: Please note, I have noticed this algorithm produces incorrect values for the cases where # quantums are 100 or greater (may be present in other cases.) I am not sure if this is indicative of a simple bug or a larger underlying issue with this approach. Can you show a proof of correctness of this algorithm?

Comment: @Idog it seems that actually it's your optimised function that's failing. See here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032311/image-quantization-with-quantums-algorithm-question#comment122378224_69234029](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032311/image-quantization-with-quantums-algorithm-question#comment122378224_69234029)

Comment: This algorithm appears to have an issue. It appears it may be overly optimistic and choosing a configuration based on a value that configuration of quantums can not attain. See for example this case that shows recomputing the value of the quantums differs from what the algorithm expects: https://ideone.com/NhTYBk

Comment: It appears the optimal value of quantums found by `f` is not the same when recomputed based on the configuration of quantums that `f` reports. Also, the optimal value claimed by `f` in the case is `20`, however when recomputing it based on the configuration it is actually `22`. Meanwhile the viterbi approach indicates the optimal value should be `21`.

Comment: @ldog please stop slandering my answer -- https://ideone.com/59cbNU

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: I'm getting lost a little bit in versions, but the version I posted in the ideone was a version of the code that you posted at one point, it may be out-dated however.

Comment: @ldog dude, I edited this 11 hours ago.

Comment: @ldog can we please just remove this conversation from under this answer? It's not helping readers.

Comment: I confirm the issue is fixed in the newest version of the answer, thanks. I don't see value in deleting the comments as they leave documentation such an issue existed at one point.

Comment: @ldog I don't appreciate you posting comments (1) [of apparent mistakes in results and concept when at the time of comment it was *your code* producing the mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032311/image-quantization-with-quantums-algorithm-question#comment122378003_69154989); and (2) [of apparent mistakes in results and concept when the code you base it on is over half a day old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032311/image-quantization-with-quantums-algorithm-question#comment122379145_69154989). That calls for taking some personal responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following:

##### step 0

Input is:

```
image = 7 2 8
        8 2 3
        9 8 255

quantums = 3
```

##### step 1

Then you  can calculate histogram from the input image. Since your image is grayscale, it can contain only values from 0-255.

It means that your histogram array has length equal to 256.

```
hist = int[256]                    // init the histogram array
for each pixel color in image      // iterate over image 
   hist[color]++                   // and increment histogram values


hist:
value  0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 0    . . .      1
---------------------------------------------
color  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10   . . .     255
```

How to read the histogram:

```
color 3 has 1 occurrence
color 8 has 2 occurrences
```

With tis approach, we have reduced our problem from N (amount of pixels) to 256 (histogram size).
Time complexity of this step is **O(N)**

##### step 2

Once we have histogram in place, we can calculate its `# of quantums` local maximums. In our case, we can calculate 3 local maximums.
For the sake of simplicity, I will not write the pseudo code, there are numerous examples on internet. Just google ('find local maximum/extrema in array'
It is important that you end up with 3 biggest local maximums. In our case it is:

```
hist:
value  0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 0    . . .      1
---------------------------------------------
color  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10   . . .     255 
           ^           ^                   ^
```

These values (2, 8, 266) are your `tops of the mountains`.

Time complexity of this step is **O(quantums)**
I could explain why it is not *O(1)* or *O(256)*, since you can find local maximums in a single pass. If needed I will add a comment.

##### step 3

Once you have your `tops of the mountains`, you want to isolate each `mountain` in a way that it has the maximum possible surface.

So, you will do that by `finding the minimum value between two tops`
In our case it is:

```
value  0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 0    . . .      1
---------------------------------------------
color  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10   . . .     255
           ^           ^  
          |  \       /   \                        
       - -      _ _ _       _     . . .   _ ^
```

So our goal is to find between index values:

```
from 0 to 2     (not needed, first mountain start from beginning)
from 2 to 8     (to see where first mountain ends, and second one starts)
from 8 to 255   (to see where second one ends, and third starts)
from 255 to end (just noted, also not needed, last mountain always reaches the end)
```

There are multiple candidates (multiple zeros), and it is not important which one you choose for minimum. Final surface of the mountain is always the same.

Let's say that our algorithm return two minimums. We will use them in next step.

```
min_1_2 = 6
min_2_3 = 254
```

Time complexity of this step is *O(256)*. You need just a single pass over histogram to calculate all minimums (actually you will do multiple smaller iterations, but in total you visit each element only once.

Someone could consider this as **O(1)**

##### Step 4

Calculate the `median` of each mountain.
This can be the tricky one. Why? Because we want to calculate the median using the original values (colors) and not counters (occurrences).

There is also the formula that can give us good estimate, and this one can be performed quite fast (looking only at histogram values) (https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/descriptive-statistics-iii-c36ecb06a9ae)

If that is not precise enough, then the only option is to "unwrap" the calculated values. Then, we could sort these "raw" pixels and easily find the median.

In our case, those medians are `2, 8, 255`

Time complexity of this step is **O(nlogn)** if we have to sort the whole original image. If approximation works fine, then time complexity of this step is almost the constant.

##### step 5

This is final step.

You now know the start and end of the "mountain".
You also know the median that belongs to that "mountain"

Again, you can iterate over each mountain and calculate the DIFF.

```
diff = 0
median_1 = 2
median_2 = 8
median_3 = 255
for each hist value (color, count) between START and END      // for first mountain -> START = 0, END = 6
                                                              // for second mountain -> START = 6, END = 254
                                                              // for third mountain -> START = 254, END = 255            
   diff = diff + |color - median_X| * count
```

Time complexity of this step is again *O(256)*, and it can be considered as constant time **O(1)**