# How can I make my output group all similar numbers into a specific number of groups?

Tags: python, list, tuples, grouping

So I wrote this code intended to let the code group different numbers from a list together in a total of `n: int` groups

**Edit** If you do not understand what the purpose of the code is, please look in the comments, I've explained it there. Thank you:)

```
def calcdifference(lst: list):
    for x in lst:
        return (x -= x)
print(calcdifference(lst=[4,5,6,4,3,2,3,4,5]))

def grouping(lst: list, n: int):
    if calcdifference(x) in list == max(calcdifference(x)):
        lst.append(x)
print(grouping(lst=[4,5,6,4,3,2,3,4,5]))
```

n: int represents the number of groups permitted from one single list, so if n is 3, the numbers will be grouped in (x,...), (x,....) (x,...) If n = 2, the numbers will be grouped in (x,..),(x,...).

However, my code prints out all possible combinations in a list of n elements. But it doesnt group the numbers together. So what I want is: for instance if the input is

```
[10,12,45,47,91,98,99]
```

and if n = 2, the output would be

```
[10,12,45,47] [91,98,99]
```

and if n = 3, the output would be

```
[10,12] [45,47] [91,98,99]
```

What changes to my code should I make?

**Note**: please refrain from using built in functions or import since I want to use as less built in functions as possible

**Important**: the code should be able to print `n >= len(lst)` combinations for every list provided

Comment: @j1-lee yep I tried to get the answer using a different approach but that failed as well, so I asked this again lol. n can not be bigger than the len(list) because the maximum number of groupings within the list is equal to len(list). Like for instance if there are 5 elements in a list, the maximum number of groupings is 5.

Comment: @j1-lee so the logic is that for the list that is inputted, We must seperate every similar number in the list and group them together. I tried using calcdifference to find the differences betwen each number in the list. And where the difference is the biggest, I plan to seperate the list into n groups. If it says n = 1, then I would look for the combination with the biggest difference and seperate it there. IF n = 2, I would look for the 2 biggest differences in the list and seperate them there. If n = 3, then I would look for the top 3 biggest differences and seperate it

Comment: See also: clustering. Perhaps something like k-means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1D Number Array Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
def grouping(lst, n):
    diff = enumerate((abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])), start=1)
    cut = sorted(x[0] for x in sorted(diff, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[:n-1])
    cut = [0, *cut, len(lst)] # add 0 and last index
    return [lst[i:j] for i, j in zip(cut, cut[1:])] # return slices

lst = [10,12,45,47,91,98,99]
print(grouping(lst, 2))
print(grouping(lst, 3))
print(grouping(lst, 4))
```

Output:

```
[[10, 12, 45, 47], [91, 98, 99]]
[[10, 12], [45, 47], [91, 98, 99]]
[[10, 12], [45, 47], [91], [98, 99]]
```

Admittedly it is quite complicated and perhaps less pythonic. There might be a more efficient way. Anyways some explanation follows...

In the first line, `diff` is a (sort of) list containing tuples `(i, d)` such that `lst` has difference of `d` between `i-1`th item and `i`th item.

The second line is more complicated. First, `sorted(diff, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])` sorts those tuples according to the second element, i.e., the tuple representing highest jump comes first.

Then `sorted(...)[:n-1]` picks the first n-1 tuples. Those will be the n-1 cuts to be used.

Generator comprehension `(x[0] for x in ...)` just picks the first item of each tuples; i.e., we no longer need the differences.

And then again `sorted(...)` will sort those cut positions, which will make the subsequent line work.

---

If you are reluctant to use `lambda` for some reason (actually `operator.itemgetter(1)` is better than `lambda x: x[1]`), you can just make a custom function for that.

```py
def get_1st(x):
    return x[1]

def grouping(lst, n):
    diff = enumerate((abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])), start=1)
    cut = sorted(x[0] for x in sorted(diff, reverse=True, key=get_1st)[:n-1])
    cut = [0, *cut, len(lst)] # add 0 and last index
    return [lst[i:j] for i, j in zip(cut, cut[1:])] # return slices
```

Comment: Thank u for ur response. However, is it possible not to use key=lambda.. like everything else is great though. I understand everything else but key=lambda and it would really help for me to u know, write a code that I myself can understand.