# How can I separate the numbers with the highest difference into different groups

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I wrote this code to find the differences between numbers.

```
def partition(lst: list):
    f = []
    l = sorted(f)
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i < len(lst)-1:
            diff = lst[i+1] - lst[i]
            l.append(diff)
        else:
            return f
```

and it works, but now I want to create another function `grouping` to separate the list where the difference between two numbers are the greatest. So like for instance if this is my list

```
[1,3,5,7,12,14,15]
```

after running `partition(lst)`, I get

`[2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1]`

So Now I want to let `grouping(lst, n)` separate the list where the difference is widest, which is 5, so I want `grouping` to return

```
[(1,3,5,7),(12,14,15)]
```

Furthermore, in `grouping(lst,n)`, there will be an int `n` as well, that will determine how many groupings are required. So basically, as long as n <= len(lst), n will be the number of groupings made.

To understand what I mean, so basically if `n = 1`, I want `grouping(lst,n)` to separate the numbers where the MAXIMUM DIFFERENCE OCCURS.

If `n = 2`, `grouping(lst,n)` should separate the numbers where the TOP TWO MAXIMUM DIFFERENCES OCCUR.

If `n = 3`, 'grouping(lst,n) should separate the numbers where the top 3 maximum differences occur. and so on..

Here is my code so far including `grouping(lst,n)`

```
def partition(lst: list):
    f = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i < len(lst)-1:
            diff = lst[i+1] - lst[i]
            f.append(diff)
        else:
            return f
print(partition([1,3,5,7,12,14,15]))
def grouping(lst: list, n):
    for x in lst:
        if partition(x) == max(partition(lst)):
            lst.append(x)
```

What should I write under `grouping(lst,n)` to make it right?

Comment: Hi the same question is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269966/grouping-the-nearest-elements-from-a-list-in-terms-of-difference
You can use that approach

Comment: Not really the same question. The question asked by Bruffff seems more complicated, since adding elements to your list may completely change where you split it.

Comment: @MehrdadDolatabadi yea that question uses itertools, and I would like to refrain fromusing that :).

Comment: What is the expected output of `grouping([1,3,5,7,12,14,15], 3)`?

Comment: the expected output would be [(1,3,) (5,7) (14,15)]. If the difference is same for all of them, just seperate the middle numbers, thats it.

Comment: the mid of all the numbers with the same difference I mean

Comment: Why split the middle numbers? Since the diff between 1/3 is the same as 3/5 and 5/7.

Comment: yea, thats kinda like default. If the difference is the same then I would like to just take the middle two numbers of that list and then return it.

Comment: @Bruffff give me the assert for n=1, n=2 and n=3 please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make my output group all similar numbers into a specific number of groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878871/how-can-i-make-my-output-group-all-similar-numbers-into-a-specific-number-of-gro)

Comment: @Bibhav yea but I would like to answer it without using key = lambda and reverse = true and start = 0. They are all good and work fine, I just want a code that a noobie like me can understand

Answer (score 0):

here my answer to your problem:

```
import numpy

def grouping(input_user, n):
    diff = numpy.diff(input_user)
    heighests = numpy.sort(diff)[-n:]
    results = []
    result = [input_user[0]]
    index = 0
    for i, cell in enumerate(input_user[1:]):
        if diff[i] in heighests:
            heighests = numpy.delete(heighests, numpy.where(heighests == diff[i])[0][0])
            result.append(cell)
            results.append(result)
            result = []
        result.append(cell)
    if result:
        results.append(result)
    return results

for n in range(1, 4):
    print(f"n={n}: {grouping(numpy.array([1,3,5,7,12,14,15]), n)}")
```

Result:

```
n=1: [[1, 3, 5, 7, 12], [14, 15]]                                                                                       
n=2: [[1, 3], [5, 7, 12], [14, 15]]                                                                                     
n=3: [[1, 3], [5], [7, 12], [14, 15]]
```

Comment: How do you do your grouping if you need to split with n=3 ?

Comment: heighests = numpy.sort(diff)[-2:] you change 2 in 3

Comment: `heighests = numpy.sort(diff)[-3:]` outputs `[[1], [3, 5, 7, 12, 14, 15]]`

Comment: and please don't use `input` as a variable! It's already a function!

Comment: The post is edited, thanks!

Comment: Still the same issue: `grouping(np.array([1,3,5,7,12,14,15]), 3) = [[1], [3, 5, 7, 12, 14, 15]]`

Comment: Good use of `np.diff` instead of reinventing the wheel!

Comment: Check the comments on the original post, I think even Bruffff does not even know how to split in this case! IMHO the more logical way to split would be `(1), (3), (5, 7), (12, 14, 15)`; 3 splits.

Comment: Ok, i change the code

Comment: Hey, thank u for ur response. I was just wondering whether is it possible to do it without importing numpy? Since I would like to use as less built in functions as possible?

Comment: @VincentBénet: `grouping(l, 3)` should split the list in 3 **indices**, returning 4 groupings.

Comment: @Bruffff: don't reinvent the wheel, unless you're really constrained. If you want you can try to reimplement `diff & sort`.

Comment: @BeChillerToo it is ok now

Comment: If it is not, give me all assert for n 1 -> 3

Comment: Seems fine to me, but since the OP did not specify how to split in case of same difference (3-1 = 5-3 = 7-5), we can't know he wants to split.