# How to sort boundary boxes from right to left and top to bottom

Tags: python, sorting, bounding-box

I have a use case where I want to sort boundary boxes from the top right to the bottom left.

> args:
> dt_boxes(array): detected text boxes with shape [4, 2]
> return:
> sorted boxes(array) with shape [4, 2]

**Example 1:**

```
[[[258.0, 52.0], [329.0, 46.0], [329.0, 72.0], [260.0, 76.0]], [[91.0, 32.0], [174.0, 43.0], [175.0, 68.0], [90.0, 64.0]], [[182.0, 45.0], [266.0, 42.0], [266.0, 69.0], [184.0, 74.0]], [[16.0, 41.0], [97.0, 39.0], [98.0, 64.0], [17.0, 69.0]], [[226.0, 4.0], [296.0, 4.0], [296.0, 32.0], [227.0, 35.0]], [[288.0, 9.0], [331.0, 2.0], [331.0, 36.0], [289.0, 39.0]]]
```

**Example 2:**

```
[[[224.0, 85.0], [381.0, 83.0], [381.0, 128.0], [223.0, 126.0]], [[412.0, 88.0], [544.0, 81.0], [545.0, 129.0], [413.0, 134.0]], [[291.0, 18.0], [357.0, 18.0], [357.0, 56.0], [292.0, 68.0]], [[122.0, 12.0], [295.0, 11.0], [296.0, 57.0], [125.0, 64.0]], [[350.0, 22.0], [435.0, 11.0], [435.0, 55.0], [351.0, 66.0]], [[442.0, 15.0], [538.0, 11.0], [539.0, 49.0], [442.0, 57.0]], [[9.0, 12.0], [125.0, 8.0], [127.0, 54.0], [10.0, 63.0]]]
```

I have used the `sort` function like this to sort using the 2nd element (**Top Right**) and 3rd Element (**Bottom Right**) in the array but it doesn't provide the correct sorting
[image]
[image]

Results to be achieved :
[image]

Boundaries are upper left, upper right, lower right, and lower left.

```
sorted_boxes = sorted(dt_boxes, key=lambda x: (x[1][1], x[1][0]),reverse=True)
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify a little bit how your bounding boxes are defined? This `[[[[[` is kinda scary. Which coordinate is which coordinate? Also, are the bounding boxes axis-aligned (ie with horizontal and vertical sides) or not?

Comment: Also please add what you are currently getting for `sorted_boxes` for your examples, and what you expect to get.

Comment: @Stef I have modified the question please let me know if it make sense now

Comment: @RufusVS current sorting is just the points to the right corner without having the top to bottom sorting

Comment: One last info that we're missing: can you please show the axes in your figure? In math it's customary to have x point rightwards and y point upwards, but in screens it's customary to have x point rightwards and y point downwards.

Comment: I think your main issue is the way you used `reverse=True`, and how that combines with wanting to sort **right-to-left, top-to-bottom** as opposed to **top-to-bottom, right-to-left**.

Comment: As a simple trick to avoid these kinds of mistake, is suggest not using `reverse=True`, and instead using negative signs inside the `key`. Instead of sorting by `(y, x)`, sort by `(-y, -x)` to reverse the order.

Comment: After your last edit, it turns out your y -axis is top-to-bottom already, so you probably want to sort according to `(y, -x)`. Assuming the upper-right corner is point number 3 in your lists, use `sorted(dt_boxes, key=lambda b: b[3][1], -b[3][0])`.

Comment: Or sort according to the centre of gravity of the boxes instead of a particular corner: `sorted(dt_boxes, key=lambda b: (sum(y for _,y in b), -sum(x for x,_ in b)))`

Comment: @Stef , Your solution is good but it doesn't work with a situation like this `[[[529.0, 10.0], [597.0, 0.0], [598.0, 40.0], [530.0, 43.0]], [[437.0, 18.0], [531.0, 12.0], [534.0, 53.0], [445.0, 60.0]], [[317.0, 35.0], [438.0, 22.0], [448.0, 68.0], [321.0, 89.0]], [[498.0, 91.0], [613.0, 71.0], [617.0, 110.0], [501.0, 134.0]], [[368.0, 105.0], [502.0, 82.0], [505.0, 126.0], [367.0, 153.0]], [[200.0, 112.0], [335.0, 110.0], [336.0, 147.0], [202.0, 157.0]], [[80.0, 134.0], [208.0, 124.0], [211.0, 167.0], [90.0, 188.0]]]`

Comment: Dear ahmedosama. I do not know what "doesn't work" mean in this case. Nor what is a "situation like this". A picture would help. Also, I provided two different `sorted(...)` suggestions, so I don't know which one you mean when you say "your solution". Note that for my first suggestion, I said *"Assuming the upper-right corner is point number 3 in your lists"*. I do not know whether that assumption is right or wrong on your lists.

Comment: Dear @Stef . Thanks very much for your help.  Number 3 on my list is in the lower-right corner.  Your help let me establish a primary solution, not perfect, My solution is to get the center point from the lower-right corners then make upper line and lower line array finally sort them individually then concatenate

Answer (score 0):

**My Primary Solution is**

1. Get the Middle point from the lower right corners
2. Create Upper Line and Lower Line Array
3. Sort two lines using the negative value of the X coordinates of upper left corner
4. Combine the two lines in one array

**Solution Code:**

```
    bottom_right_corners = [r[2] for r in dt_boxes]
       
    mid_point = (np.amax(bottom_right_corners, axis=0)[1] - np.amin(bottom_right_corners, axis=0)[1]) // 2
    top_labels = []
    bottom_labels = []
    
    for dt_box in dt_boxes:
        if dt_box[1][1] <= mid_point:
            top_labels.append(dt_box)
        else:
            bottom_labels.append(dt_box)
    
    print (f"Top Line Len {len(top_labels)} , Bottom Line len {len(bottom_labels)} and Medium Point {mid_point}")
    sorted_boxes_top = sorted(top_labels, key=lambda x:  -x[0][0])
    
    sorted_boxes_bottom = sorted(bottom_labels, key=lambda x: -x[0][0])
    
    _boxes = [*sorted_boxes_top , *sorted_boxes_bottom]
```

> My solution is not working if I have more than 2 lines. Any suggestion

Comment: Instead of creating the two lines manually, you could do clustering on the y-values. Each cluster corresponds to 1 line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering for instance.