# Splitting a list of N values into K groups/clusters with minimal standard deviation within each group

Tags: java, algorithm

Need to split a list of positive values into a K groups. The groups should be almost equal in size (number of values), but the values of items in each group have the minimal standard deviation. (Think grouping products by similar pricing).

I was thinking sort the values, then split by order into K groups gets me very close and then only if the groups sizes aren't all equals do one-pass to see if the extra items moved from one group to the next creates a better result.
But I feel like I'm missing something big here and it should be more complicated than that.

Comment: a.) what have you tried so far? can you show any code? b.) you tagged both java and javascript. which one is it?

Comment: llook up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering ;-)

Comment: I removed JS code though both would work for us. I didn't write any code yet as I feel I'm missing something very basic and it's not as simple as I make it. Will write my solution shortly if it helps.

Comment: @MBobrik Yes, I've seen that which is why I feel I'm missing something basic here with my solution which is far from np-hard...

Comment: quote "The problem is computationally difficult (NP-hard); however, *efficient heuristic algorithms converge quickly to a local optimum*." ... so you basically got one of those heuristic solutions.

Comment: @MBobrik No, in one dimension this is NOT NP-hard. In 2 dimensions it is.

Comment: @btilly to be honest, never thought about the 1D special case in detail - but never mind, others did - just found this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a complication.

Suppose that `k` is even and `n = 2.5*k`.  Then half your groups are of size 2 and half of size 3.  With a naïve approach, you have to consider the `k choose 2 = O(2^k / sqrt(k))` possible ways to decide which are of size 2 and which are of size 3.  This will take exponential time.

Let `m` be the group size, rounded down.  Then the optimal division of the first `i` items into `j` groups will be to have either `m` elements in the last group and divide the first `i-m` items into `j-1` groups, or to have `m+1` elements in the last group and divide the first `i-m-1` items into `j-1` groups.  You can calculate that with a recursive function which returns a pair for `(cost, linkedListOfChoices)`.

Add a caching layer to that recursion and it will run in polynomial time.  This is called top-down dynamic programming.

Going from your optimal `linkedListOfChoices` for dividing the whole list into `k` groups to the actual groups should be straightforward.  Here is an example.

Suppose we want to divide `[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 2.1, 2.3]` into `4` groups.  You should get a linked list corresponding to (but maybe with a very different representation):

```
[8, 9,
    [5, 7,
        [2, 4,
            [0, 1,
                null]]]]]
```

From which your groups (read inside out, turn indices back into numbers) are:

```
[[0.1, 0.2], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.8, 0.9, 1.0], [2.1, 2.3]]
```

Comment: Sorry for being slow, I think I got most of what you wrote and it makes sense but now I'm not sure is the success criteria / minimal "price" for the overall thing that I measure? the optimized solution? is it summing up all the deviation values for each group and looking for the minimal sum?

Comment: @dean734 Exactly.  Minimum sum of deviations so far, and the trail of decisions that got you there.

Comment: Is this a well-known problem with an implemented algorithm in a library somewhere?

Comment: @Leo The caching technique is well known and is called memoizing. Lots of languages have libraries to help with that. The recursive function is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of sorting first is correct. Then you have to create K groups from the sorted array, which you can do as following: If there is any deviation you can play around the "border elements" of each group to make the result better.

For example: N=16, K=3. Now there are some possible outcomes. First group 5 memebers, second group 6 members and last group again 5 members, but there are other possibilties to create your groups. Now you need to find and evaluate all the possibilities, and pick out the best one. For example, if shape [5,5,6] is better than shape [5,6,5] you move the last element ("border element") from the second group into the third group.

If there is no deviation at all, for example N=100, K=10, there is only one possibility you can choose, and that is the best one in this case.